# Get files from computer in Putty

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ssh, putty

I am using Putty to SSH into a Linux computer from Windows so I can use bash instead of cmd.
However, there is a file I need to use that is already on my Windows computer that I want to get. How can I get it?

What I have tried:

I tried wget pathname but I got an error saying "unable to resolve host address 'c' ". That makes sense. 
So I tried seeing if I could get it through the local host some way, but I really wasn't sure of a clear way to do that, so it didn't work out.

Thanks

Comment: psftp on windows. send file windows->linux.

Comment: you shouldn't ask such questions, you could find  that with simple search over internet

Comment: @MarcB  Okay I am looking through this here: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html and want ed to know, when it says I am supposed to run psftp from the path, does it mean run it from cmd, or is there another client I am supposed to use?

Comment: @MortezaLSC Actually, when I looked it up, I got more stack overflow answers which didn't help me. Since they were old questions, I thought it best not to ask about the solutions on an old post. So, I asked it again. Maybe I should have stated that.

Comment: You are really welcome to ask any question you want, I just had a recommendation to you...I hope my answer could help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a practical tool called `winscp` and you can download from [HERE](http://filehippo.com/download_winscp/).

If you want to know what `winscp` is read this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP).

Answer (score 0):

If you have putty installed you probably already have pscp.  If not just go to the putty download site and download it.

Then assuming you have this configuration:

```
host: 192.168.1.33
unix username: john
unix password: secret
```

and on that server you ssh to your home directory and in your home you have a file important.txt, then to download using pscp you would use this command:

```
pscp john@192.168.1.33:./important.txt .
```

then you are prompted for your password.  This downloads to the current folder on your local machine.

You can also specify the password in the command like this:

```
pscp -pw secret john@192.168.1.33:./important.txt .
```

And you can also download to a different local folder as in:

```
pscp -pw secret john@192.168.1.33:./important.txt c:\backup
```